# Android Asynch Task inside AlertDialog not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I display an Alertbox with ok or cancel.
I want to implement an asynch task on the press of OK. Havent done asynch and been struggling with it for awhile. I dont understand where the asych class goes also. Does it go outside the method that is being executed or outside of it? Current code as follows:

```
 private abstract  class DoAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> 
 {
  protected  void doInBackground()
  {
   Drawable drawable= getImage(imageSelect);     
   MakeWallPaper(drawable,1);
  }

  /* protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
  {
   setProgress(progress[0]);
  }*/

  protected void onPostExecute() 
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper Saved.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
   AlertDialogProcessing=0;
  }
 }

 public void getWallpaper(final View v)
 {
  if(AlertDialogProcessing==0)
  {  
   final String title="Set Image to Wallpaper";
   final String message="Press OK to set as Wallpaper or CANCEL.\nWait after pushing OK.";
   final String ok="OK";
   final String cancel="CANCEL";
   final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   alertbox.setCancelable(true);
   alertbox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
   alertbox.setTitle(title);
   alertbox.setMessage(message);
   alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel, null);
   final AlertDialog dlg = alertbox.create();

   alertbox.setPositiveButton(ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
   {  
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int which)
     {  
       DoAsynchTask.execute(null,null,null);  //<<<<Wrong
       dlg.dismiss();
       Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 
     } 
    });
    alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ public  void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1){AlertDialogProcessing=0;                     
     Vibrate(ClickVibrate); } });
 alertbox.show();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Its `new DoAsynchTask().execute(null,null,null);` . Try this.

Comment: Remove `abstract` on you AsyncTask implementation and use `new DoAsynchTask().execute()' start it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple problems in the code.

**1)** First of all, the compiler is probably giving you this message:

> The type MyActivity.DoAsynchTask must implement the inherited abstract
>   method
>   AsyncTask.doInBackground(Void...) MyActivity.java

If you look closely at the error message, you'll realize that what you defined was this:

```java
protected  void doInBackground() {
```

which is not what is needed.  Even though it might seem silly, when your `AsyncTask` subclass takes `Void` as the generic parameter types, that means that `doInBackground()` must look like this:

```java
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
```

The compiler complains because you haven't implemented that (exact) method.  When you inherit from an `abstract` class, and fail to implement **all** of its required/abstract method(s), then you can only get it to compile by marking the subclass as abstract, too.  But, that's not really what you want.

So, just change your code to (remove `abstract` from your class):

```java
private class DoAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
```

and

```java
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
{
   Drawable drawable= getImage(imageSelect);     
   MakeWallPaper(drawable,1);
   return null;
}
```

**2)** And the second problem, as others have pointed out, is that you must start your task with:

```java
new DoAsynchTask().execute();
```

not

```java
DoAsynchTask.execute(null,null,null);
```

Your code would only be correct if `execute()` was a `static` method in `AsyncTask`, which it's not.  In order to invoke the non-static `execute()` method, you first need a `new` instance of the `DoAsynchTask` class.  Finally, the `null, null, null` parameter list is also not necessary, although I don't think it will cause the code to fail either.

Comment: I made changes as recommended, but I am getting this error on new DoAsynchTask().execute();  Cannot instantiate the type DoAsynchTask.  The other question I have is where do I place the Asynch Task? Inside the method? Inside someplace inside the main Activity?  This Asynch task is called from inside an onClick method.

Comment: Thank you for posting code snippets. And thank you all for your time. I have it working now and will post corrected copy for others.

Comment: @user1445716, it sounds like you got it worked out, but just for the benefit of others, **where** you already had the DoAsynchTask was fine ... as a private inner class in the same .java file as where it's used.  And, the reason it wasn't letting you instantiate `DoAsyncTask` was that you didn't remove the `abstract` modifier from the `DoAsynchTask` subclass.  I implied that it wasn't necessary, but probably wasn't as clear as I should have been that it needed to be removed.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `doInBackground()` does not specify any parameters, you should call `DoAsynchTask.execute()` without parameters.

Why is your class abstract? Normally an AsyncTask should be an inner class of the activity starting it. So create your dialog in the activity, and execute the AsyncTask when clicking on OK button, like you do.

Comment: Eclipse insists it needs to be abstract. So I place the Asynch task inside the Activity (only got one).  Then I try to execute it with SetWallPaperTask.execute(); I get error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method execute(Void...) from the type AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>"

Comment: So are you actually calling the task from a static method? Since you don't access any instance variables in `doInBackground()`, you can make it static as well. But i've never experienced that Eclipse wants me to make it abstract

Comment: Asynctask sholud be executed from from UI thread ... from out side Activity you cannot execute it...........

Answer (score 1):

//final working copy -Thanks ALL

```
public void getWallpaper(final View v)
{
 Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 

 final class SetWallPaperAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> 
 {
  @Override
  protected  Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
  {
   Drawable drawable= getImage(imageSelect);     
   MakeWallPaper(drawable,1);
   return null;
  }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
 {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
  AlertDialogProcessing=0;
 }
}

if(AlertDialogProcessing==0)
{    
 ProgressDialog progress;  
 final String title="Set Image to Wallpaper";
 final String message="Press OK to set as Wallpaper or CANCEL.";
 final String ok="OK";
 final String cancel="CANCEL";

 final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 alertbox.setCancelable(true);
 alertbox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
 alertbox.setTitle(title);
 alertbox.setMessage(message);
 alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel, null);
 final AlertDialog dlg = alertbox.create();

 alertbox.setPositiveButton(ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
 {  
  public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
  {  
   new SetWallPaperAsynchTask().execute();
   dlg.dismiss();
   Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 
  } 
  });
  alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ public void  onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1){AlertDialogProcessing=0; Vibrate(ClickVibrate); }   });
  alertbox.show();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Which target SDK version did you use? My last examples were for 2.3 or SDK r10, respectively. There the `doInBackground` method had no parameters, if not needed. This `Void... arg0` must be intrduced in a later version...